# Is stackoverflow codebase available?

Tags: support, api

I am seeing some sites outside of stackoverflow family implementing the same code like http://answers.onstartups.com/.
Stackoverflow codebase is not open source. How did Dharmesh Shah (the owner of OnStartups) use the same look and feel for his site? Is Stack Overflow available in some form so that someone can start a site like http://answers.onstartups.com/, which exactly works like Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 4):

http://answers.onstartups.com is a stackexchange site (a site in the Stack Exchange family)

Before the current range of `http://sitename.stackexchange.com` sites (SE2.0 sites) there were a few sites that used the Stack Exchange engine but were for external sites (SE1.0 sites)

When the 1.0 sites were replaced with 2.0, the staff of the Stack Exchange couldn't just say we're stopping access to your site or something similar, so there a few sites that look like they aren't part of the Stack Exchange, although they are.

However there are sites which have stolen the UI of Stack Overflow and they have nothing to do with the Stack Exchange (not authentic).

Authentic sites have the footer that is at the bottom of this site (and every other Stack Exchange site) and a StackExchange button in the top left.

Comment: It's actually using the current codebase (see the lower right corner), just not some `.stackexchange.com` URL. It's also [listed](http://stackexchange.com/sites) on stackexchange.com. I think, but I am not sure, that all 1.0 sites have meanwhile been disabled? (For 10k: [here's an old list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40784/is-this-a-stack-exchange-website/40787#40787).)

Comment: @Arjan - There are still SE 1.0 sites, not at all involved with stackexchange.com though, for example http://mathoverflow.net/ and such...some *may* still come over to be 2.0 sites (I hope not, it'd be *so* painful now), or they may never come over.  We're hosting them on some VMs separately from the rest of our environment though, so they're just kind of "there" trucking along for the moment.